# Using fread function and errors in input

Tags: r

I'm experimenting some problems while writing a script and using the function fread. Here my code along with some explanatory comments:

```
 #From the file "Collar_#.txt", just select the columns ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y, ACTIVITY_Z and Event

    dataraw<-fread("Collar_41361.txt", select = c("ACTIVITY_X","ACTIVITY_Y","ACTIVITY_Z","Event"))

    #Now, delete all rows containg the string "End"

 datanet<-dataraw[!grepl("End", dataraw$Event),]

    #Then, read only the columns ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y and ACTIVITY_Z until row 150 from datanet

train2<-fread(datanet,header=TRUE,select=c("ACTIVITY_X","ACTIVITY_Y","ACTIVITY_Z"),nrows=150)
```

To see a sample of how `datanet` is organized [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D77PA.jpg)

Now, after executing the last line of the code, I get the following error message:

```
Error in fread(datanet, header = TRUE, select = c("ACTIVITY_X", "ACTIVITY_Y",  : 
  input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r
```

I get that `fread` input should be the name of a file but can't it be `datanet` which is an object from my script? How can I then solve this problem so I can read table `train2` which is basically `datanet` without column "Event" and down to row 150?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: the `fread` input must be a string. for what I understand, you want to save into `train2` the `datanet` object without the `Event` column, right? in that case simply use `train2 <- datanet[, !'Event']`

Comment: Yes thank you! Now, what about reading `train2` object just until the row 150 (as an example)? I'm using `train2 <- datanet[, !'Event',nrows=150]` but it's not working. I'm not sure I can use nrows here.. Ideally, I would like something where I can set the interval of rows I want to look at, [1 to 150] for example.

Comment: please take a look at the documentation! `dt[i, j, by]` is the basic syntax of the `data.table` object. if you want to subset rows, just use the `i` argument, whereas if you want to subset columns use the `j` arg. in this case `train2[1:150, !'Event']`.

Comment: Yes! Just figured that out by myself now I was just going to delete my comment. Thanks anyway